# Simple key based lookups in Deedle Frame

Tags: f#, deedle

Suppose we have some data as follows:

```
name        age   eats
bugs bunny  20    carrots
elmer fudd  50    wabbits
```

What is the Deedle equivalent of the following Pandas example?

```
>>> df[df["name"] == "bugs bunny"]["eats"]
0    carrots
Name: eats, dtype: object
```

or

```
>>> df[df["eats"] == "carrots"]["name"]
0    bugs bunny
Name: name, dtype: object
```

If there is another more F-sharpy way to do these kinds of lookups (e.g. using records) that would also be very useful.

Thanks.

[EDIT]
I guess using records it would be as follows:

```
type PersonRec = {name : string; age : int ; eats : string}
let rec1 = { name = "bugs bunny"; age = 20; eats = "carrots" }
let rec2 = { name = "elmer fudd"; age = 50; eats = "wabbits" }

let bugsbunnyeats =
    [rec1; rec2] 
    |> List.filter (function
                        | {name = "bugs bunny"}   -> true
                        | _                       -> false
                    )
bugsbunnyeats.Head.eats
```

But I would still like to see the same operation using Deedle if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deedle has concept of row & column keys - this makes it super easy to perform lookup based on the key, but for lookup based on other columns/rows, you'll need to use filtering.

Given your sample data:

```
let df = 
  frame [ 
    "age" =?> series [ "bugs bunny" => 20; "elmer fudd" => 50 ]
    "eats" =?> series [ "bugs bunny" => "carrots"; "elmer fudd" => "wabbits" ] ]
```

This creates a frame:

```
              age eats    
bugs bunny -> 20  carrots 
elmer fudd -> 50  wabbits
```

Now you can use various lookups:

```
// Lookup using column & row keys
df.["eats", "bugs bunny"]

// Lookup using row key
df.Rows.["bugs bunny"].GetAs<int>("age")
df.Rows.["bugs bunny"]?age // for numbers

// Lookup using filtering
let carrotEaters = 
  df.Rows
  |> Series.filter (fun k row -> row.GetAs("eats") = "carrots")

carrotEaters.FirstKey() // bugs bunny
carrotEaters.FirstValue().GetAs<int>("age") // 20
```

Comment: Very nice summary of indexing to Deedle! For this to work from records the rows have to be indexed: `let df = recs |> Frame.ofRecords |> Frame.indexRowsString "Name"`

Answer (score 0):

Once you say lookup, the equivalent data structure becomes a map/dictionary. Then you can do a map of maps, or just keep it simple in this case, map of records. Of course Deedle will abstract most of this but here it is for a map:

```
type PersonRec = {Name : string; Age : int ; Eats : string}
let rec1 = { Name = "bugs bunny"; Age = 20; Eats = "carrots" }
let rec2 = { Name = "elmer fudd"; Age = 50; Eats = "wabbits" }
let recs = [rec1;rec2]
type subRec = {Age: int; Eats:string}
```

Create a simple map:

```
let m1 = Map.empty<string,(int * string)>
let m1 = recs |> List.map ( fun x -> (x.Name,{subRec.Age=x.Age;subRec.Eats = x.Eats})) 
              |> Map.ofList

m1.["bugs bunny"].Eats 
//val it : string = "carrots"`
```

And who eats carrots?

```
m1 |> Seq.filter (fun (KeyValue (k,v))-> v.Eats ="carrots") 
   |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Key)
//val it : seq<string> = seq ["bugs bunny"]
```